# Synthetic "migration" operations in tzkt.io - any way to get them from the node?

Tags: rpc

I have a problem similar to [this one](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2144/different-types-of-operation-in-tezos-block-which-one-fee-is-spent/2146#2146). We have full node and sync blockchain data to our DB by calling RPC API /chains/main/blocks/N. We have come across some addresses balances for which differentiate by 1 millitezos from the one shown by most explorers. I found tzkt.io explorer and there spotted "babylon airdrop" operation of kind "migration", not mentioned among block's operations.

Is there a way of getting such operations via node's RPC, or any other way to know this operation took place for address A and not for address B, without using tzkt.io API? For example, I know that `tz1KeK8qEnZhFzLQqnz2oKaXnG4X2zQC5tz3` has "babylon airdrop" migration at block height `655360`, and foundation baker `tz3UoffC7FG7zfpmvmjUmUeAaHvzdcUvAj6r` has "bootstrap" migration at block `1`. How does tzkt.io know about those "migrations"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context migrations are hardcoded in the protocol initialization module. There are no migration operations at all, just a piece of code which somehow changes node's database.

We at [tzkt.io](https://tzkt.io) analyze the source code of the protocol and do some kind of reverse engineering to understand whether the database was migrated and what exactly was changed. We do painstaking work to accurately replicate these changes in the form of `migration` operations to make full account history visible to users, so you can safely rely on [tzkt.io](https://tzkt.io).

However, you can always check it in the Tezos source code. For example, "Babylon airdrop" can be found here: 
[/src/proto_005_PsBabyM1/lib_protocol/init_storage.ml#L94-99](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/proto_005_PsBabyM1/lib_protocol/init_storage.ml#L94-99)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the "Babylon airdrop" balance updates weren't visible from the protocol to explorers, so most explorers included this on their own.

A fix to include balance update receipts from migrations is very likely to be included in a future proposal.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to get them from official source linked to tezos foundation, rather than from tzkt.io? For example, https://tezos.foundation/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/5223213-genesis.txt is file having among other information bootstrap balances. Does something similar with Babylon airdrop exist?

Comment: We currently don't have something that's similar to this for the Babylon airdrop. We'll see if we can compile such a list though.