# What is a manager operation?

Tags: protocol, operation, fees

Transactions, originations, public key reveals, and delegations are "manager operations". According to [Different types of operation in Tezos Block - Which one fee is spent](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/q/2144/338), "manager operations spend fees". However, I don't find this definition very clear. Is there a better characterization of such operations? Why are they called "manager"?